# Report Viewer not displaying window

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have here some problem with report viewer. 
It doesn't display the report viewer and I really
don't know what the problem is.

Here is my code

```
private ServerReport LoadReportViewer()
        {
            ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer.ServerReport;
            serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerURL"]);
            serverReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerPath"];
            var paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
            paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("ID", ID.ToString(), false));
            paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("UserID", UserID.ToString(), false));

            ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
            return serverReport;
        }
```

aspx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="90%" ShowExportControls="False"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: Did you add the result from this function to your report viewer?

Comment: i included the function on the page_load

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, it's really confusing having an instance name equal to the class name, I recommend to change your control's ID to another one so you cannot get wrong on if you are using the class type or your instance.

Comment: I already figure out what my problem is. It is on the javascript. im passing on the wrong function name. but this code is working.

Comment: Yes, I'm not telling it should not work, it's just confusing.

Comment: I do not believe you need to assign `ServerReport` or call its `Refresh` method at the end. Otherwise the code in question is fine.